# Long Term Support Branches in git?

Tags: git, branch, enterprise

I'm working for an enterprise company, developing software for macOS.

I'm not sure how to solve my problem by supporting multiple versions of a software, in one single git-repo.

The product is an Xcode project for macOS, code is managed by git.

At current there is one release out there: 
version 1.0

Every version is valid until next major version will be released. So v1.0 is valid and maintained until v2.0. But v1.0 should now be a "long term supported branch" - means if v2.0 is out there, v1.0 is still maintained.

How can I solve my problem maintaining v1.0 and v2.0 and maybe v3.0 in future? 
How can I fix a bug in v1.0 and in the same time in v2.0?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching) with [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tagging) to handle multiple "trees" in a single repo. Take a look at [Ruby on Rails repository](https://github.com/rails/rails) as the example. They have `x-y-stable` branches for different versions.

To port commits from one branch to another, you can use [cherry pick feature](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

Answer (score 2):

When you fix something in one version, you can cherry pick the commit unto another branch if the same fix applies there (which will not always be the case, because the various versions will divert more and more over time, making certain fixes non transferable).

See:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Answer (score 1):

Assuming master is your current production version, every time you do a release then tag master with the version number (i.e. v1.0, v2.0, etc). So let's assume you have done that for versions 1.0 and 2.0 and begin work on version 3.0. You should have an integration branch created from the 2.0 release and call it, say, next-release.  The next-release branch would contain all the bug fixes and enhancements (typically each bug fix and enhancement would be in their own work branch and then merged into next-release when properly peer reviewed).

As bugs are reported against 1.0 or 2.0 you should first confirm the bug exists in next-release. If so make the fix and cherry pick the fix as the prior user suggested. If the bug only exists in 1.0 or 2.0 then you can create a work branch from the 1.0 or 2.0 tag and make the fix there.